# Hibernate querying

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm sorry for my maybe foolish question. I have products and orders tables (with many-to -many relationship), also i have an user table. And now I want to get the product count by user_id and by special field "order_satus". I can make two queries get order by special criteria and then get size of product in order. But this is not optimal at all. When i use JDBCTemplate I did a lot of joins and get only one query.

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop.order")
public class Order {
@Id
@Column(name = "order_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long orderId;

private long user_id;

@Column(name = "databegin")
private Date dateBegin;

@Column(name = "dataend")
private Date dateEnd;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private User user;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "order_product", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "order_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") })
private List<Product> products;
}
```

Product Entity

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "product")
    public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int product_id;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "order_product", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "order_id") })
    private List<Order> order;

    public List<Order> getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(List<Order> order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Column
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Max(value = 250)
    private String descr;

    @Column
    @Max(value = 250)
    private String manufacturer;

    @Column
    private Double price;

    @Column
    private Byte[] barcode;

    @Column
    private Byte[] picture;

    @ForeignKey(name = "category_id")
    private int category_id;
```

Comment: What is your problem, exactly?

Comment: where is the column `order_satus`?? In which table?

Comment: Sorry forget about order_status in **order table** but it really exist. Problem is that i want to make only one query that will give me count of product in order with one of statuses. How to make it using Hibernate. cause in SQL it will be something like 'select count(*) from produtc p join order ord on ord.id = ? and ord.status = ?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you gave sql query..

> 'select count(*) from produtc p join order ord on ord.id = ? and
>   ord.status = ?' – Igor Masternoy

And according to the Entity structure you gave, the HQL will be..

```
select ord.products productList from Order ord where ord.id=? and ord.status=?
```

This query will return you list of products (`List<Product> products`) and then you can get the count by java code i.e. `productList.size();` This size is the product count you need based on order id and order status you will pass as parameter and also you can append `user.id` in where cause to filter your result as per user.

This is productList as per your need..

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("select ord.products productList from Order ord where ord.id=:orderID and ord.status=:orderStatus");
query.setInteger("orderID", orderIDParameter);
query.setString("orderStatus", orderStatusParameter);
List<Product> productList = (List<Product>) query.list();
Integer productCount = productList.size();
```

This productCount is your product count you need.

Comment: What is productList? productList alias?

Comment: See i have edited the post for more clarification on `productList`.
Assuming that orderStatus is a String field.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you can have many orders for one user, and many products for one order.

I think a good option is to use a DetachedCriteria and to build your query with it.

Should look like (not tested):

```
DetachedCriteria userCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class);
userCriteria.add(Projections.groupProperty("user_id"));
userCriteria.add(Projections.count("product_id");
DetachedCriteria orderCriteria = userCriteria.createCriteria("order.user_id","order",CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
DetachedCriteria orderCriteria = orderCriteria.createCriteria("order_product.order_id","product",CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
//orderCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq(...); // I can't see a "status" field in your model

List results = userCriteria.list();
```

Comment: I 'll test this later, but it look great. thx to all Stack overflow my best javafriend=)

Answer (score 0):

```
select size(ord.products) from Order ord where ord.id = :orderId and ord.status = :orderStatus
```

or

```
select count(*) from Order ord join ord.products where ord.id = :orderId and ord.status = :orderStatus
```

The first form will result in a subquery to get the count.  The second relies on the join to create the sql product over which to apply the count.  The first form is more intuitive, in my opinion, while the second query will perform better in most cases.